# Jar Manifest changes getResource() path

Tags: maven, jar, classpath, manifest

I have a critical problem after building a jar file via maven. I told the maven-jar-plugin to use several classpaths. The created jar contains the following manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25
Main-Class: EntryPoint
Class-Path: Launcher-1.0.jar lib/ Introduction-1.0.jar
```

But when I try to load a resource from a method in EntryPoint.class, the root path is /xx/xx/lib/ and I am not inside the jar file, it is the lib/ folder which was specified in the Manifest.

This is the snippet I use inside the method of EntryPoint:

```
System.out.println(EntryPoint.class.getResource("").getPath().toString());
```

BUT: I need to load an xml file inside the jar, how can I get back?

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.swing.ImageIcon ICONE     =new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("path/subdir/video.png"));
```

OR

```
Icon ic2=new ImageIcon(ThisCurentClassName.class.getResource("/fr/package/someresource/icones/server1.png"));
```

Comment: my image (*.png)  are packed in the jar

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!